# show that the norm topology and the weak topology on a space $X$ can be different.

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that the norm topology and the weak topology on a space $X$ can be different.

weak: $x_n \rightarrow x \iff f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x). \forall f \in X'$

strong: $x_n \rightarrow x \iff \sup\{|f(x_n) - f(x)| :f \in X', ||f|| \leq 1\} \rightarrow 0$

What i tried:

Take $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x) = x^2$, then obviously $||f|| = 1$ and and $f(x_n) \rightarrow 0 = f(x)$, but the supremum of this function is when $n = 1$. and is $1$ not $0$

Comment: It's not clear what $X$ is supposed to be in your example.  Do you just mean $X = \Bbb R$?

Comment: yeah i took the real space, but one can take a hilbert space or banach space as well, i am trying to look at $l^2$ now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Since you mentioned $\ell^2$, consider the sequence defined by $e^{(k)}$, where
$$
e^{(k)}_j = \begin{cases}1 & j=k\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: ok, so i tried to take the orthonormal basis of $l^2$ and $f(x) = <x,e_i>$ where $i$ is a chosen number. Then $||f|| = ||e_i|| = 1$ and obviously:

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e_n = 0$ and $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$. So this is weak but if we look at the strong convergence:


$\sup\{|<x_n,e_i>|\} = 1$